# Is there a way to access Apache2's SetEnv variables through PHP CLI?

Tags: php, apache2

I need to run a php script to refresh data every 10 minutes, and I'm doing it using cron.

crontab -e configuration is:

```
*/10 * * * * php my_file.php
```

In this file, I'm using `$_SERVER['my_env_var']` to retrieve the value of the variable, which is an encrypted string (it is set in apache2.conf as `SetEnv MY_ENCRYPTED_VALUE` something).
Using debug in web browser will correctly output the values (it is being run with apache, so it can **read the file** and recognize I'm calling the variables set on the server).

However, cron is using the CLI. And when using

```
<?php
    print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

my variables are not listed in here.

I do understand they do not share the same `.ini` files and SAPIs (apache2handler vs cli).

I have seen other posts that say:

> "Set them as `/etc/environment` variables"

but if possible I would prefer not to use that (is it secure?).

But, is there a way to access Apache2's `SetEnv` variables through PHP CLI?

Comment: Apache is not even involved, when you execute your script directly on the command line via the PHP executable.

Comment: _“In this file, I'm using $_SERVER['my_env_var'] to retrieve it.”_ - what _is_ “it”, what kind of value do you need to transport, and why this way?

Comment: @CBroe I mean to retrieve the value of the variable. I am storing encrypted values to connect to a database, so I do not want them to be accessible directly in a php file. 
I set them as SetEnv variables in the conf file (I removed read, write and - who would? - execute permissions to group & user, left rights for only the superuser).
I know apache is not involved through the CLI but I need to retrieve those values :(

Comment: What makes you think that setting the variable in the Apache configuration is in any way more secure than using any other configuration file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said, cli has no relationship with PHP in cli mode. And you still need some common environment variable, you can take help from CI CD pipelines. It will keep those secure and at one place.

We are talking about almost same thing, i am saying that env should be written by the pipeline to target system, rather manually maintained by some individual team.

CI CD pipeline give us a way to use env variables for any reason and security is very good candidate to use that.

Comment: Please share more details. Why should "CI CD pipelines" be involved after all on a production system?

Comment: they should be involved in production system infact in development and staging should also be served by CI CD. He can keep secure password in GitHub and push them as environment variable even in one+ places, these environment will not be written in files even, I suggested this as his problems is different not the Apache or code related. does it make sense?? I can explain it more.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it. I still don't get why one should not configure the target server properly, and how your approach should do this using pipelines